# Is it possible to use treeData and unstable_cellSelection together?

Tags: mui-x

MUI-X has two awesome features: `treeData` and `unstable_cellSelection`. But these are in different tables (DataGridPro and DataGridPremiuim).
Is it possible to use  these features together?

to use `treeData` and `unstable_cellSelection` in one table. I need it for clipboard